# Opening links in a new tab, Jquery

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

Is there a way to take:

```
$(function(){
  $("#myDiv a").attr("target","_blank");
});
```

and say all links in `#mydiv` that don't have a class of `btn` should open in a new tab?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `:not` modifier in the selector.

```
$("#myDiv a:not(.btn)").attr("target", "_blank");
```